# How to deal with the extremely large expressions in Fortran?

Tags: fortran90

I have a fortran program like this,

```
program test
integer,parameter :: f=selected_real_kind(20)
Real(kind=f)::b1,b2,c1,v,xd,xe,res
b1=1._f
b2=0.5_f
v=1._f/3._f
c1=0.25_f
xd=0.2_f
xe=1._f/6._f
res= "extremely large expressions"
write(*,*) res
end program
```

res is just a very large expression, which is more than 50000 lines. And I cannot compile this program using gfortran compiler. The error reason is, out of memory allocating 65536 bytes
    Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you simply break it up in intermediate results and/or function calls?

Comment: @eriktous  Yes, this is one way. However, I want to find a better method.

Comment: I'd suggest to break it up. The fortran standard (2008) only allows 255 continuation lines, everything above that is compiler dependent.

Comment: What is the nature of the expression? One rarely encounters large expressions that cannot be broken into more logical ones, (like regression expressions or similar which can be written in matrix format)?

Comment: @ldigas In fact, it can be broken into more logical ones. However, I want to find a more elegent way.